# GWT-OpenLayers: Navigate and Box Selection Together

Tags: gwt, openlayers, gwt-openlayers

Consider [this example](http://demo.gwt-openlayers.org/gwt_ol_showcase/GwtOpenLayersShowcase.html?example=Select%20and%20edit%20feature%20example) on GWT-OpenLayers showcase. The example implements the navigate and box selection features separately. How can I implement the navigate and box selection feature together? i.e. I make a selection only when I press 'Shift Key' or 'Ctrl Key', and navigate rest of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following which worked for me.

Create a map with no control using:

```
defaultMapOptions.setControls(new JObjectArray(new JSObject[0]));
```

Then add custom controls to the map. (Here I'm adding just one)

```
map.addControl(new PanZoomBar());
```

The `PanZoomBar` can help in the panning as well as zooming. This fixes the navigation. As for the box selection,

```
SelectFeatureOptions selectBoxFeatureOptions = new SelectFeatureOptions();
selectBoxFeatureOptions.setBox(true);
SelectFeature boxSelectFeature = new SelectFeature(vectorLayer,selectBoxFeatureOptions);
boxSelectFeature.setClickOut(false);
boxSelectFeature.setToggle(false);
boxSelectFeature.setMultiple(false);
boxSelectFeature.setToggleKey("ctrlKey");
boxSelectFeature.setMultipleKey("shiftKey");
map.addControl(boxSelectFeature);
```

[Additional Reference](http://vasir.net/blog/openlayers/openlayers-tutorial-part-3-controls)